# Derived attribute absent in JSON response in Sails.js

Tags: json, rest, sails.js

I'm writing an API for users in an example app. The `api/models/User`-file looks as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    fullName: function () {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
  }
};
```

However, when I `find` all my users, the derived attribute is nowhere to be found in the response:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Marlon",
    "lastName": "Brando",
    "createdAt": "2015-09-13T10:05:15.129Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-09-13T10:05:15.129Z",
    "id": 8
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Bjoern",
    "lastName": "Gustavsson",
    "createdAt": "2015-09-13T10:05:36.221Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-09-13T10:05:36.221Z",
    "id": 10
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Charlie",
    "lastName": "Sheen",
    "createdAt": "2015-09-13T10:06:59.999Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-09-13T10:06:59.999Z",
    "id": 11
  }
]
```

Am I missing something, or is it simply not possible to derive attributes like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are set attributes in Model with function it doesn't mean that it will be executed in resulting attribute. It means that you can call this function in your code. For instance, I have exactly your `User` model. I can make in my code smth like this:

```
// api/controllers/UserController.js
module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    User
      .create({firstName: req.param('firstName'), lastName: req.param('lastName')})
      .then(function(user) {
        console.log(user.fullName());
        return user;
      })
      .then(res.ok)
      .catch(res.negotiate);
  }
};
```

If you want to make it like a dynamic attribute, then you should take a look at `toJSON` method in your model. You can override it and implement your own logic. I think it will looks like this in your case:

```
// api/models/User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    lastName: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    fullName: function() {
      return [this.firstName, this.lastName].join(' ');
    },

    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      obj.fullName = this.fullName();
      return obj;
    }
  }
};
```

I didn't check this code but think that should work. You can play around with `toJSON` method and see what you got. Ping me in comments if code doesn't work.

Comment: Perfect Eugene :) Been playing around with Sails for a couple of days, and this was like the last piece of the puzzle for me. Thanks a lot.